# Laplace transfom of $\int_t^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du$

Tags: laplace-transform

I want to know the Laplace transform of the function: $\mathcal{L} \int_t^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du$.

I tried the following method

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ts}\int_t^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du dt=\int_0^{\infty} (\frac{e^{-ts}}{-s})'\int_t^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du dt =-\frac{1}{s}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ts}\frac{f(t)}{t} dt$.

Using the relationship

$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ts}\frac{f(t)}{t} dt = \int_s^{\infty}\mathcal{L}f(t)dt$

I obtained the following final expression:

$-\frac{1}{s}\int_s^{\infty}\mathcal{L}f(t)dt$

But it may be wrong because it is different from the expression in the comment of [Find the inverse Laplace transform of $f(t) = \int_t^\infty \frac{e^{ - u}}{u}du$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388259/find-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-ft-int-t-infty-frace-uudu?newreg=725d03e7fba54ac1b3d552c45b5f86e4), which is

$\mathcal{L}\int_t^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du = \frac{1}{s}\int_0^{s}\mathcal{L}f(t)dt$

I'm not sure if the following holds

$-\frac{1}{s}\int_s^{\infty}\mathcal{L}f(t)dt = \frac{1}{s}\int_0^{s}\mathcal{L}f(t)dt$

I'm very grateful if you could show me the derivation.

Comment: Are you sure of the limits of the integral ?

Comment: Sorry I put a wrong limit on the right-hand-side of last expression. I have edited.

Comment: are you sure of this $\int_u^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du$? Shouldn't it be $\int_t^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du$?

Comment: Yes, $\int_u^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du$ is what I'm calculating.

Comment: @rapid_train That doesn’t really make sense. You can’t have the variable of integration and one of the limits of integration be the same while also doing well-defined math.

Comment: Perhaps with specified $f$ you find the answer $$ \int_u^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du=\mathcal{L}(\frac{f(t)}{t^2})$$
$$ \mathcal{L}\int_u^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}du=\mathcal{L}\mathcal{L}\left(\int \int f(t)\right)$$ with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thanks for the tips. I've changed the expression.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi It seemed like an ill definition, so I have changed the expression like what you suggested.

Comment: The integral you want to compute is $\mathcal{L}[f](s) =  \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ts}\left(\int_t^{\infty} \frac{f(u)}{u}{\rm d}u\right) {\rm d}t$. Notice the use of different letters for the integration variables $t$ and $u$ compared to yours ($u$ and $u$).

Comment: You fixed the first line, but you still have the same problem through the rest of your post. I don’t know if it’s necessarily harming anything, but having your integrals set up appropriately should help you find an answer to your question.

Comment: @Winther Thanks for the point. I've fixed and tried further calculations given the new equation.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I've edited the whole sentence.

Comment: You forgot the boundary term when doing integration by part: $\int u v' = \color{red}{uv} - \int u'v$. In this case that term will be something like $[e^{-ts}/(-s) \int_t^\infty f(u)/u{\rm d}u]_0^\infty = \frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty f(u)/u{\rm d}u$ which is not zero. If I'm not mistaken this term should give an extra $\frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty \mathcal{L}f(t){\rm d}t$ which combines with what you have to give the correct answer.

Comment: @Winther I see, I omitted the calculation. Now it's all clear, thanks everyone!